# Adding Extra Conditions to MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Having problems modifying an existing MySQL query and every time I try I
keep getting parse errors or MySQL warnings/errors. I have looked at previous
questions and tried various things but just can't seem to get it right and it 
must be something simple.

**Here is the working query**

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT count(list_id) AS counter 
    FROM bookings 
    WHERE 
        '". $date_form . ($i - ($startday + 1)) ."' BETWEEN checkin_date 
        AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        AND appmt_id = ". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['appmt_id'])
);
```

I want to simply add:

AND is_deleted = 0

is_deleted is a field in the table containing either 0 or 1

Have tried with brackets, quotes etc - apologies for the simple question and thanks
in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show the non working query?

Comment: echo out the query before executing it and see if it looks odd.  Also surround the variable you are equating to appmt_id with single ticks.

Comment: Have tried various things - the code in the original works fine - it's just my addition that doesn't work. Here was my last attempt  mysql_query("SELECT count(list_id) as counter FROM bookings WHERE '".$date_form.($i - $startday + 1) ."' between checkin_date and DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and appmt_id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['appmt_id']) AND (is_deleted == "0"));

Comment: In mysql equal operator is = not == . Also remove brackets if is_deleted is boolean

Comment: just tried it again with one = and the error I get is: 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' '

Comment: Tried it without the brackets and get the same error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine if the field is called "is_deleted":

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT count(list_id) AS counter 
    FROM bookings 
    WHERE '" . $date_form . ($i - ($startday + 1)) . "' BETWEEN checkin_date AND DATE_SUB(checkout_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
      AND appmt_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['appmt_id']) . "
      AND is_deleted = 0
");
```

Comment: Thanks Dan - spot on works perfectly now - will save this for future reference as I have spent too long on this ;-)